# Delete current website and install wordpress godaddy

Tags: wordpress, cpanel

I have a website on godaddy linux hosting. It was developed with bootstrap. I am a beginner I want to erase the current website data and install wordpress on it. Can anyone suggest how can I do. Thanks.

Comment: Its easier its called migration

Comment: so how can I do??

Comment: I dont want old website, I want to create a new website with same account but on wordpress

Comment: no problem with that

Comment: hi, you want that data back to new website ?

Comment: thanks for your answers guyz. It is solved :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to **convert it to WordPress structure** or make new one.Its inside a local server and when you want to make it live then following step are useful.

**Installation step for WordPress website :**

Step 1: Export Database File

Step 2: Modify File Paths

Step 3: Create New Database on Your Hosting Account

Step 4: Upload Database File into New Database

Step 5: Fix wp-config.php File

Step 6: Uploading Website Files

Step 7: Modify Permalinks

You can read more here : 
http://www.wpexplorer.com/wordpress-local-to-live/

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the steps:

1. Login to your godaddy control panel
2. Select Manage Hosting
3. Now click on File Manager. Select domain (if you have multiple website setup).
4. You will see list of wordpress files there. Select them all and press delete.
5. Now go back to manage hosting and select your database. Open phpmyadmin and drop all tables.
6. Go back to manage hosting and in the Popular Apps section, click WordPress.
7. Now it will show you all the steps, mostly you have press next and follow some easy instructions.

Also if you want to manually install the Wordpress then download it from here: https://wordpress.org/download/ and follow these steps:

1. Upload the zip to public html directory.
2. Uncompress it and it will create a folder "Wordpress"
3. Move all file from this folder to one step up (Public Html) folder.
4. Now hit your domain URL and follow the steps. I will ask for database username, password, host and additional information regarding website title, admin username etc. and you are done.

Comment: please check existing site on  bootstrap